# Asp.net Core Identity with Fluent Validation?

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I'm wondering if it is possible to replace the built in Asp.Net Core 2 Identity validation with Fluent Validation? I did a fair amount of searching, but did not find any examples.

Comment: What you mean exactly by "built-in ASP.NET Core 2 Identity Validation"? Could you provide an example of it?

Comment: In Visual Studio when you create a new web application with authentication, the default identity validation.

Comment: You can [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) , then customize it to fit your requirement